# How roll log file every 10 minutes with NLog

Tags: nlog

```xml
 <targets name="GFGLogInfo" xsi:type="BufferingWrapper" bufferSize="2000" flushTimeout="5000" slidingTimeout="false">
        <target  xsi:type="File"
                openFileCacheTimeout="10"
                keepFileOpen="true"
                archiveNumbering="Date"
                archiveEvery="Hour"
                archiveDateFormat="yyyyMMddHH"
                archiveFileName="${basedir}/../GFGLogs/GFGLog/{#}.log"
                fileName="${basedir}/../GFGLogs/GFGLog/${date:format=yyyyMMddHH}.log"
                bufferSize="10485760"
                layout="${message}" />
    </targets>
```

I would like to ask how to set up a log file every 10 minutes. Currently, I have one log file every hour

.Try for an hour, okay, but want to set it to 10 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do this:

```xml
<target xsi:type="File" name="GFGLogInfo"
        fileName="${basedir}/../GFGLogs/GFGLog/${date:format=yyyyMMddHH_mm:truncate=12}.log"
        layout="${message}" />
</target>
```